# LoRa and Manufacturing Technology

Tags: manufacturing, lora

Which manufacturing technology do the LoRa (Semtech SX1276) belong to? Is it a CMOS based chip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this chip will be based on a CMOS process, it is the only way to make such a chip in an economic way. This chip has a transceiver working up to 1020 MHz which is perfectly possible in most common CMOS processes.

Anyway, why would you need to know this? How does it matter what manufacturing technology is used? Read the datasheet to learn how to use this chip. I do not see how the process technology that is used is relevant to anyone else than the manufacturer and maybe a competitor that wants to develop a similar chip.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was a doubt arouse when I went through some research papers about using capacitors in low power design.